# receiving data from bluetooth device to android app

Tags: android, bluetooth

We have developed a health tracking app.However we need to fill the TextView spaces from the data we got from Bluetooth Blood Pressure device.To be able to do this, which info of bluetooth device's we need to find out? How can we get data from a bluetooth device to our application

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). you seem not to have researched yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need API documentation of your device. As an example for Omron devices you should [request](https://omronhealthcare.com/api/) documents for developers from the vendor.

Comment: the company we are using products of, is not sharing API or any info. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Have you ever looked at this?  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#HDP